# Codeigniter Cart library cannot support cyrillic chars

Tags: codeigniter, cart, cyrillic

I faced an issue that I cannot add item to cart if it contain cyrillic name. In Cart.php I added to variable symbols а-я:

```
var $product_name_rules = 'абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя\.\:\-_ a-z0-9';
```

But it not resolved issue. When I changed an item name to latin it is added to cart.

Comment: it seems that it works :
$product_name_rules = '\p{Cyrillic}\.\:\-_ a-z0-9';
preg_match("/^[". $product_name_rules."]+$/iu", $items['name']);

Comment: it return аЙбббб? ,but must йяюэъ ???

Comment: for last comment it return correct string, but I don't set encoding for browser so that's why I get string in another encoding.

However I still get error in Cart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add unicode flag to pregmatch in _insert function:

```
if ( ! preg_match("/^[".$this->product_id_rules."]+$/iu", $items['id']))
```

and

```
if ( ! preg_match("/^[".$this->product_name_rules."]+$/iu", $items['name']))
```

There is good article about this issue: http://wwarlock.blogspot.ru/2010/03/codeigniter.html